# Good compact camera with a good burst mode and a low shutter lag

Tags: point-and-shoot

Can anybody recommend a good compact camera that has a

1. Good burst mode.
2. Low shutter lag.

I know the DSLRs have these features and so do the micro four thirds.
But the DSLRs are too bulky and micro 4/3s a little too expensive. Something in the range of 300$ to 500$ would be nice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "pro" compacts such as Canon S95, Canon G12, Panasonic LX5, etc have decent low shutter lag compared to typical compacts.  It really isn't significantly more than Micro Four Thirds which you mentioned, and with some pre-focusing can be virtually instantaneous.  Try out a Canon S95 in a store to see.

The burst rate of these are pretty good too and will compare favourably with Micro 4/3 too.

The Olympus XZ-1 can do 7 or 15 fps in burst mode albeit at a smaller frame size than normal.

In my experience Micro 4/3 is not that expensive when you compare it to a similar setup from Nikon or Canon.  Nikon and Canon entry level kits are nice and cheap beating m4/3 but the DSLR price benefit goes IMHO away once you move on from the kit lens in both.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few of these models now. What you need to look for is a compact with a CMOS sensor. These can take burst up to 40 FPS, although most do 10 FPS, at full-resolution with an extremely short shutter-lag.

Just use [Neocamera's Camera Finder](http://www.neocamera.com/search_camera.php) and search for Compact AND CMOS sensor to get the full list. Today's results show 8 cameras: h[ttp://www.neocamera.com/search_camera.php?size=compact&sensortype=cmos](http://www.neocamera.com/search_camera.php?size=compact&sensortype=cmos).

The Casio Exilim EX-FC100 advertizes a shutter-lag of ZERO! It uses a trick called pre-buffering where it continuously captures images at 40 or 60 FPS and saves the one in its buffer when you press the shutter. You can even calibrate to match how quickly you press the shutter. Without that feature it still shoots at 40 FPS.